# Commit symlink into subversion

Tags: svn, symlink

I'm tring to commit a symlink into subversion, but I get this error when I try to add the actual symlink:

> Can't replace 'path/to/symlink' with a
>   node of a differing type; the deletion
>   must be committed and the parent
>   updated before adding
>   'path/to/symlink'

Comment: If you are on a legacy system (ie svn version 1.6.x) see below

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I read it as - you have to remove the file, commit, update, create symlink, add it, commit.

And my guess is that you're trying to remove the file, create symlink, commit in one go.

Comment: I did delete something earlier that was previously in the place I'm tring to symlink to but I committed my change before trying to add the symlink to subversion.

Comment: "and the parent update". Maybe you need to `svn update` for whatever reason?

Comment: I've edited the update step into my answer for future sufferers.

Comment: When removing, a "svn delete --keep-local" might be useful.

Answer (score 13):

1. svn delete x
2. svn ci -m'blah'
3. **svn update**
4. ln -s blee x
5. svn add x

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type l | xargs -i -x svn propset svn:special on {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error I got on svn 1.6.11 reads

> svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: Entry '/path/to/symlink' has unexpectedly changed special status

I fixed it by simply

```
svn propset svn:special on /path/to/symlink
```

And then rerunning the commit.  Apparently no need to delete, update, etc....