# SVN commit failed due to Pod files attribute change with "unexpectedly changed kind" error

Tags: ios, svn, cocoapods

I am getting failed error when trying to make a commit on SVN:

> svn: E145001: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: E145001: Node '/Users/Hemang/Workspace/SVN/Project/iOS/Source/MyApp/Pods/Headers/Private/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.h' has unexpectedly changed kind

What's the issue?

Even if I am checking status with `svn status` command, it showing me status like this:

```
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIActivityIndicatorView+AFNetworking.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIAlertView+AFNetworking.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIButton+AFNetworking.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIImage+AFNetworking.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIKit+AFNetworking.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIProgressView+AFNetworking.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIRefreshControl+AFNetworking.h
~       Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/UIWebView+AFNetworking.h
```

What can be the issue?

When I search for `~` attribute, it says that, "type changed". But I have not done anything with the Pod file. And yes, I have also tried installing the latest Pods but it doesn't help.

Comment: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-users/201409.mbox/%3CCALMaGmeG9jmBD3Aju6dQGF_UStRG-LCPoCFZ7COsuV4KHF6umA@mail.gmail.com%3E & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312343/how-to-switch-folder-to-symlink-in-svn

Comment: This question deserves an answer, perhaps an explanation of what the error means. Simply linking to another occurrence of someone who had the error (as in the comment above) is not helpful.