# How to keep includes in SVN

Tags: svn, clearcase

I am moving from clearcase-lite (CC-LT) to SVN.

In clearcase we link every C++ header file in central folder (Include) in order to simplify the make-file configuration. 
For example:

```
Folder1/a.h
Folder2/b.h
Folder3/c.h
Include/
        a.h --> ../Folder3/a.h
        b.h --> ../Folder3/b.h
        c.h --> ../Folder3/c.h
```

And Make file contains:

```
-I../../Include
```

Currently, in clearcase, **each link under Include folder is an element.**

Now that we are moving to SVN I wonder if that is the best way to handle this.

Do I need to keep the same concept and import also the symlink files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to keep the same concept

Considering that SVN can keep the same directory structure, the simplification you got from those symlinks will apply as well for the same makefile.
So yes, you should consider keeping those.

> import also the symlink files?

Yes, but check how they are imported. If they are converted as element as well, you will need a post-import step in order to [delete them/replace them with proper symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1478461/6309).

Comment: Thanks @VonC, it seems like it worked - when I checkout this project the files that supposed to be links stayed links.